# How to fix "mysqli::real_connect(): SSL operation failed" error?

Tags: php, mysql, ssl, openssl

Environment: 
Ubuntu **14.04**, PHP **5.5.9**, MYSQL **5.6.30**

From time to time I get an **error**

> `mysqli::real_connect():` SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL

Error **message:**

> error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Front/nginx is on one server and mysql is on a different server.

The error is not continuous, it happens randomly and I find those error messages in error log so I cannot really do full debug.

**Sample:**

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$this->objMySqli = mysqli_init();
mysqli_options ($this->objMySqli, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);

$this->objMySqli->ssl_set($this->SslKey, $this->SslCertificate, $this->SslCACertificate, null, null);

$link = $this->objMySqli->real_connect($this->Server, $this->Username, $this->Password, $this->Database, $this->Port);      

if (!$link) {
    throw new QMySqliDatabaseException("Unable to connect to Database", -1, null);
}
```

**SSL Cipher:**

[image]

**It fails on this line:**

```
$link = $this->objMySqli->real_connect($this->Server, $this->Username, $this->Password, $this->Database, $this->Port);
```

Comment: Did you allowed the SSL2 and SSL3 cyphers on your server? Does the server allow SSL2?

Comment: Are you using PDO or direct mysqli::real_connect() ? If using PDO, try using direct call, it should give more useful errors...

Comment: @MarcoS - added my script

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel - added screenshot

Comment: Have you been blocked for too many connection failures?  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blocked-host.html

Comment: @AndrewHenle - shouldn't I get different error message then?

Comment: @AndrewHenle - I have tested and I'm getting "MySqli Error: Too many connections" when I decrease max_connections in my.cnf

Comment: @CroiOS *shouldn't I get different error message then?*  I don't know the answer to that one - I've never gotten the error using a PHP client.  *I have tested and I'm getting "MySqli Error: Too many connections" when I decrease max_connections in my.cnf*  That was the wrong way to go - it's not a problem with `max_connections` if too many failures have caused MySQL to block an IP address from connecting.  Read the error messages you'll see and the corrective action(s) needed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blocked-host.html This *might* be your issue - you need to investigate.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - it was problem with that mysql version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is problem with mysql version 5.6.30, 
I have updated to 5.6.32 and now this error is not happening anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading didn't fix my problem, but I did find a new solution.

> **TLDR;** Convert your PKCS#8 format keys to PKCS#1 format keys
>
> ```
> openssl rsa -in example.com.server.key.pem -out example.com.server.key.pkcs1.pem
> ```

I ran into these bugs:

[MySQL Bug 71271](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=71271)

[MySQL Bug 64870](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=64870)

Essentially, if your private key is in PKCS#8 format instead of PKCS#1 format, MySQL will not "find" the private key.

A lot of Stack Overflow answers say rename the header and footer to include RSA in the header and footer like so:

From (PKCS#8 format)

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

To (PKCS#1 format)

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

However, this does not change the private key data between the header and footer. When using my PKCS#8 format key with the modified header and footer, no error occured at MySQL startup, but when I tried to connect with mysqli I got

```
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number
```

By converting my private keys to PKCS#1 format, the keys worked and I could connect fine:

```
openssl rsa -in example.com.server.key.pem -out example.com.server.key.pkcs1.pem
```

Note that newer OpenSSL versions, at least 1.0.2j (what I was using) output PKCS#8 keys when using

```
openssl req -config "openssl.cnf" \
-keyout "private/example.com.server.key.pem" -new -sha256 \
-days 3652 -nodes -out "csr/example.com.server.csr.pem"
```

but using different options may output PKCS#1 keys (possibly `-newkey rsa:2048`, I haven't tested). Which would explain why only some people are experiencing this when using openssl generated private keys.

This problem occurred form me in MySQL 5.6.17 and 5.7.14, so it seems like the bugs are not fixed.